# How do I perform some command action other than responding to the client within a signal R server?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I have a self hosting signal R server running on Asp .Net Core and have my hub class which receives messages from clients. I would like to perform some command action upon receipt of messages, such as adjust the pan and tilt of my device. Every example I have seen only communicates back to clients. I am using SignalR as a realtime protocol without a web page and so would like other components to hook into events that get generated from the hub.

My startup class is as follows

```
namespace SignalRServer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/myControllerHub");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And my controller hub is as follows

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignalRServer
{
    public class MyControllerHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not so familiar with web apps but understand that Signal R is a good choice for real time web based communications. Any help appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:
Perhaps the component that performs the command action should be another client, rather than having the server performing the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SignalR uses hubs to communicate between clients and servers. A hub is a high-level pipeline that allows a client and server to call methods on each other. In the server code, you define methods that are called by client. In the client code, you define methods that are called from the server. SignalR takes care of everything behind the scenes that makes real-time client-to-server and server-to-client communications possible. More detail information about using SignalR, check the following articles:

[Use hubs in SignalR for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#create-a-signalr-hub)

> I would like to perform some command action upon receipt of messages,
> such as adjust the pan and tilt of my device. Every example I have
> seen only communicates back to clients. I am using SignalR as a
> realtime protocol without a web page and so would like other
> components to hook into events that get generated from the hub.

In the hub method, you can do command action(such as CRUD action), and then send the updated information to client ([Call client methods from hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#call-client-methods-from-hub)). Besides, you can also do the command action via Ajax on the client, then in the success function, using SignalR to send a notification message to other clients and let them update the content. It is similar to the chat application. You could also search `data update using asp net core signalr example` online, there should be multiple samples you could refer them.